# how to use "for x in <list >"

Tags: list, python-3.x

```
a = []
for index in range(52):
    a.append([])
    for jindex in range(52):
        a[index].append('a')

row,col = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]

b = []

for index in range(row):
    str = input()
    for jindex in range(col):
        a[index+1][jindex + 1] = str[jindex]
        if(str[jindex] == 'A'):
            b.append([index,jindex])

#print (a)
# print (b)

ans = max(trav(x[0],x[1]) for x in b
```

The last line is troublesome,
trav(r,c) is a function that return integer values.

I just want to ask is this usage correct? I am very new to python. 
I tried to extend this line from `row,col = [int(x) for x in input().split(" ")]`

I am trying to store the max value the function trav returns for each list of 2 items stored in the list b.

Like: if the list b is `[[10, 20], [2, 3]]` and lets say the func trav returns the sum of the 2 items in the sublist.

then the first sub list gives us 30, and then second gives us 5. So ans should have a value 30

Comment: This isn't closely related to your actual question, but `str` is the name of a built in type. While it's not illegal to redefine it, it's almost always a bad idea to do so. One reason is because it is confusing! It took me a while to understand what `str[jindex]` was doing.

Comment: @Antimony: Not so in Python 3 (which this question is tagged with). `input` is now equivalent to `raw_input` from Python 2.

Comment: @Blckknght Oops, missed the tag. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just add the missing right parenthesis at the very end of the last line.  The `trav(x[0],x[1]) for x in b` forms a generator expression that generates the value of `trav` for each element of `b`, and then `max()` iterates over that generated sequence and returns the maximum value found.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah I figured it out 'ans = max([trav(x[0],x[1]) for x in b])'